# iptables actively refused everything despite exceptions

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, firewall

I was following the centos wiki page on iptables but no mater what I change only port 22 opens. Using various port scanning websites they all say the server is actively refusing connections on all other ports.

Here is the iptables -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:urd
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:pop3
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:pop3s
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:imap
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:imaps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

From what I understand INPUT (policy DROP) should drop all traffic that does not have a defined rule, and I set the rules to accept port 443/25/465 exc. but they all show up blocked. Yet port 22 (ssh) is unblocked and works fine.

Does anyone understand what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: What commands are you actually inputting?

Comment: sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

Comment: Please post the output for `netstat -anp`

Comment: posted it. I still have no idea why it blocks everything but ssh.

Answer (score 0):

Its been awhile since I've done iptables but I think you want to have a rule that always allows established connections:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

See this post: [What is "state RELATED,ESTABLISHED" in iptables?](https://serverfault.com/questions/557115/what-is-state-related-established-in-iptables)

Comment: Still blocking everything, thanks though.

Comment: you might need to specify it for each port as in `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

Comment: did iptables -F, redid all the rules that way, no effect.

Answer (score 0):

*sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT*

All that command does is add a rule allowing SSH connections over tcp port 22.

You need to:

**-Load the state module**

*iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT*

**-Set the default policy on a chain**

iptables -P INPUT DROP

**-Set default policy to drop**

*iptables -P FORWARD DROP*

**-Then you start establshing rules ala:**

*iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT*

or

*iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 192.168.0.0/24 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT*

**or allow all incoming SSH, HTTP and HTTPS traffic in one line**

*iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22,80,443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT*

*iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --sports 22,80,443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT*

Comment: Tried, did not work. Thanks though. Still blocking everything but port 22.

Comment: Did you change the rules according to ports like iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

Comment: Yep. Am I wrong in thinking that iptables -F opens all ports if all policy's are set to accept? Because right now I have 0 rules, everything on accept and it's still blocking everything but port 22. Maybe Iptables is not the problem.

Comment: Your being locked out by the default filter policies not being removed when you run the iptables -F command; you're setting the policy to default deny/accept and then flushing all the rules that let you in. -F flushes all the rules...that's your problem. You are deleting all existing rules everytime you run -F

Comment: That's exactly what im trying to do. If I have all ports open, no firewall blocking anything and i'm still being blocked then something is wrong with my system.

Comment: @MSQLnoob020983 You will be actively rejected (blocked) on all ports that don't have a service listening on them.  If you only have SSH running then all other ports will be blocked.  This is how TCP/IP works, nothing is wrong with your system. IPTables reject rule behave the same as a port that has no listener.

Comment: @BillThor Well dam. That solved it. Thank you. I had installed apache on the server but forgot to set the service to start every time on boot. When I could not get the default index.html page to display I jumped to "something must be wrong with the firewall".

Answer (score 0):

Two thoughts:

1) Do you have services running on those other ports?  (netstat -an)
2) Is the server hosted somewhere, like a home ISP, that doesn't allow incoming connections on those other ports?

Comment: 1. I'm not entirely sure what i'm looking at with netstat. It dumped a lot of stuff to console. 2. It's a digital ocean virtual server. I have quite a few running, all same OS and iv never had this problem before.

Comment: Try to run netstat -an | grep 80 to see if http is listening.  Substitute 443 and 25 for https and smtp, respectively.  Post results back here.